# How can I get the next month End Date from the given Date

Tags: c#

I am implementing a code to find quarter start date and End date every thing was implemented fine but if user enters a date like `2011,2,1` I would like to get the `quarter` end date based on this date

```
DateTime dtTempStartDate = new DateTime(2011, 2, 1);
var qrtrDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dtTempStartDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"), "MM-dd-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var dtMnthEnd = qrtrDate.AddMonths(1);`
```

should I add `days` or `add milliseconds` can some one help me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int quarter = (int)Math.Ceiling(qrtrDate.Month / 3.0);
int lastMonthInQuarter = 3 * quarter;
DateTime lastDayOfQuarter = new DateTime(qrtrDate.Year, lastMonthInQuarter, DateTime.DaysInMonth(qrtrDate.Year, lastMonthInQuarter));
```

Comment: This is giving `2011,2,28` but I need to get quarter end date i.e `2011,3,31`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the next month end date, you can use this formula:

`=DATE((YEAR(A1)),(MONTH(A1)+1),(DAY(A1)))`